# how do I refresh data from a resolver that uses a verb?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I refresh the `connections` resolver? After a user followers another user, I need to refresh the list of connections.

```
.controller('UserShowCtrl', function ($scope, connections) {
...

    connections.??()
        .then(function(connections){
            $scope.connections = connections[userId];
        });
...
});

$routeProvider
    .when('/u/:username/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/users/show',
        controller: 'UserShowCtrl',
        resolve: {
            connections: ['$route', 'User', function($route, User){
                return User.connections({ id: $route.current.params.id}).$promise;
            }]
        }
    })
```

Here is the resource:

```
.factory('User', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/users/:id/:verb', {
        id: '@id'
    }, { //parameters default
        update: {
            method: 'PUT',
            params: {}
        },
        get: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                id: 'me'
            }
        },
        connections: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                verb: 'connections'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `connections` injected into the controller should already be resolved so you should be able to do

`$scope.connections = connections[userId];`

**Update**: If you want to refresh at specific times you would have to use the method on `User` service and hence inject that service into the controller. Like this

`User.connections({ id: $route.current.params.id}).$promise
      .then(function(connections) {
              $scope.connections = connections[userId];
       });`

The `connections` dependency passed in constructor is just s simple array.

Comment: I see no API call being made. I want to `refresh` the data.